# How "ping" an interface without IP address?

Tags: linux, ethernet

I need to check if an ethernet interface is "up and running" even if it doesn't have an IP address associated and ARP is not supported. I know only its MAC address: do you have an idea on how to "ping" this interface?

I was thinking to perform this ping by sending something based on "Ethertype" values: I don't know what I could obtain if I send a no-supported Ethertype value to Linux.

It is only an idea, probably not the best one.

Any suggestion?

Comment: this may help ... google `ethernet switch discovery protocol`

Comment: The original Ethernet used a shared communication medium where anyone could receive anyone's transmissions. As a result, the NICs were designed at the hardware level to ignore any transmissions not meant for them, to minimize the CPU load. So, if you send with an Ethertype value that is not supported by the receiver, the receiver is expected to just ignore it. This might happen at the NIC hardware level, before the operating system is involved at all. So, the trivial approach of "just send anything to it" won't work: you need to find some protocol to which the target will respond.

Comment: If it is ethernet ARP *must* be supported. Otherwise, something is not being told here.

Comment: If the same Linux system has an other interface with an IP address set and didn't enable rp_filter (reverse path forwarding), then ARPing that other interface's IP from an adequate IP source will get an answer from the interface without IP (if it's the only connected to the probing system, else results are random, the main interface could answer instead). weak host model in action.